# How do I view the documentation of the `novel` class?

Tags: document-classes, documentation

I tried `texdoc novel` and got many (over 30) errors of the form

```
 (134): Illegal character <22> in hex string
```

How do I use the class?

I also tried `pdflatex novel-example` with no success.

Comment: I get a pdf with texdoc, but the main documentation seems to be in html: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/novel/doc/novel-documentation.html

Comment: `novel-example.tex` requires lualatex.    Only change: the magic comment from % !TeX TS-program = LuaLaTeX to % !TeX TS-program = lualatex. (Using MiKTeX+ TeXstudio)

Comment: Thanks to the two respondants. I also got a pdf with texdoc but with over 30 reported errors. Doesn't give a safe feeling. I eventually found where `novel-example.tex` was situated (`kpsewhich` did not find it) and changed the magic comment to get it processed via `lualatex`.

Comment: Magic comment fixed in version 1.80 of `novel`. The capitalized LuaLaTeX only succeeds in the TeXworks editor.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of `novel`. Its documentation is in HTML, not PDF. And, its *tex files must be run with `lualatex` (not `texdoc`).

Just re-processed some files with `novel` (TeXlive 2022, Linux). No problem.